# Preproccessed field not appearing in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a news content type with an optional CCK field, "field_source".  This is intended for external news items, like something on Yahoo News.  In Views, I have a display which links the node title to the field_source.  If the content author does not provide a field_source, I want it to default to the node->path.

To accomplish this, I created a preprocess function and added it to my template.php file.  The problem is that the View is not using the updated value.  Do I need to place the function elsewhere?

```
function content_preprocess_content_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['field']['field_name'] == 'field_source') {
    $source = $vars['items'][0]['url'];
    $node = $vars['element']['items'][0]['#node'];
    if (empty($source)) {
      $vars['items'][0]['url'] = $node->path;                                                                                                 } 
  } 
}
```

TIA,
Aaron

Comment: My View uses fields, is that the problem?  I'm using Views Slideshow, so I have to use fields and not node. Hmmm...